# Spring Boot ApplicationConfig UserDetailsService when username is not unique

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in my application username (email) is not unique. It has to be paired with companyId. The same email can exist in different companies which are all being held in the same database.

The problem lies in the Bean initiating the userDetailsService in applicationConfig. Whatever I try to do I get different errors. In the current state it says: "'findByEmail(java.lang.String, java.lang.Long)' in 'wmi.inzynierka.repository.UserRepository' cannot be applied to '(< lambda parameter>, < lambda parameter>)'"

**Application config:**

```
  @Bean
  public CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
    return (username, companyId) -> repository.findByEmail(username, companyId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
  }
```

**userRepository**

```
Optional<User> findByEmail(String email, Long companyId);
```

***CustomUserDetailsService***

```
public interface CustomUserDetailsService extends UserDetailsService {
    UserDetails loadUserByUsernameAndCompanyId(String username, Long companyId) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
}
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming userRepository is derived from JpaRepository interface, the method signnature is not correct.

You have two options:
Implement a custom repository and create the query yourself.
Second option is to try change the method signature to something like:

```
Optional<User> findByEmailAndCompanyId(String email, Long companyId);
```